# A show with 3 characters like power rangers

Tags: story-identification, tv

Can somebody tell me the name of the show? It was with 2 police officers one had a talking sword and other had a talking gun and the last one had a stick like thing. It was just like power rangers but not that. The one with sword was blue the one with gun was white&red and the last one was maybe silver&orange.

Comment: Cartoon? Live-action? And how did it differ from Power Rangers? Did they have civilian identities? A floating head mentor? Giant robots? Who were they police officers for?

Comment: If someone does post a correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

There was a show named [*Madan Senki Ryukendo*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madan_Senki_Ryukendo)

[image: Image of the three warriors]

It correctly matches the description which you gave, as the main character Kenji Narukami is having a talking sword (named GekiRyuken) and the other guy, his friend is having a talking gun.

The show also portrays another character (the one having a sword like thing), Ryujino.

### Opening

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Embedding wasn't working well on my phone :(

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a long-shot, but could you be thinking of Saban's *[VR Troopers](https://metalheroes.fandom.com/wiki/VR_Troopers)*? It features three characters. It was Saban's first attempt to capitalize on *Power Rangers* with a different property. The color somewhat match what you remember and they did wield weapons. However, they were not explicitly police, and their weapons didn't talk on their own (although it seems the AI Professor Hart would talk to them in the field, which could seem like their weapons talk to them).

> The show focused on three young adults in their late teens, Ryan Steele, Kaitlin Star, and J.B. Reese, living in the fictional West Coast town of Cross World City. They regularly attended and were teachers at "Tao's Dojo", a karate studio. Ryan was the most focused martial artist; J.B. was the computer wizard; while Kaitlin was a photographer & budding reporter for the local newspaper, the Underground Voice Daily. One day, Ryan's search for his long-missing father led him and his two friends to a strange laboratory. Inside, a digitized head of Professor Horatio Hart, a friend of Ryan's father Tyler, explained the truth about his life's work of having developed extremely advanced virtual reality technology in secret. "VR" is a dimension existing alongside our own; within it lie mutants and monsters bent on conquering both worlds. The main ruler of these is a creature known as Grimlord, who, unbeknownst to anyone on Earth, has a human identity as billionaire industrialist Karl Ziktor. As Karl Ziktor tries to overcome the barriers of the true reality to allow his armies easy passage from virtual world, the responsibility falls to Ryan, Kaitlin, and J.B. of defending the planet on both sides of the dimensional barrier. They have assistance in the form of armored bodies having incredible firepower. This included eventual additions to their arsenal, such as a Turbo Cycle, Techno Bazooka, and a flying, laser-blasting Skybase.

[image: The VR Troopers]

### Trailer

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this might be the [Beetleborgs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bad_Beetleborgs) series.

My memory of the series is pretty cloudy, but the blue Beetleborg had a little sword type weapon ([Stinger Blade](https://metalheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Stinger_Blade_(Beetleborgs))), the red one had a gun-type weapon ([Striker blaster](https://metalheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Striker_Blaster)), and the green one had a claw ([Hunter claw](https://metalheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Hunter_Claw)).

I'm not sure how well this fits.  I don't think they were cops (though their visors  remind me of Robocop), and I'm not sure if their weapons talked.  They had a bunch of technology though, so that wouldn't really surprise me.

This seems like a bit of a wild guess; just the blue guy with a sword and red one with a gun, along with the power rangers-like style made me think of this series.